# UIKit Vue.js graphics bug - reload?

Tags: html, css, typescript, vue.js, getuikit

I am currently building a frontend with Vue.js and UIKit. I have multiple Views and when I go to another View the dropdowns from the navbar unfold and the images wont load. After I reload the page everything is as it should be. any ideas on what could be causing that and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

[bevore reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MelK5.png)
[after reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVzsP.png)

I have reloaded the page, but as far as code i have no idea where to start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.